# how to pass a model to view in ajax-based request in mvc4

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating an ajax-based Quiz in MVC. Below is the Question view. When the form is submitted I save the user selection in the controller then need to send the next question to the view without reloading the page. Is it possible to send/update the model from the controller in the ajax request

```
@model  DataAccess.Question
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Survey";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
  @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Survey", "Tools", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "QuestionContent", HttpMethod = "Post", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { QuestionId = Model.QuestionId }))
    {
        <div id="QuestionContent">
            <h2>Welcome To Quiz</h2>

            <fieldset>
                <p>
                    Question
                    @Model.QuestionId of @ViewBag.QuestionCount:
                </p>
                <p>
                    @Model.Description.
                </p>
                <ul style="list-style:none;">
                    @foreach (var item in Model.Answers)
                    {
                        <li> @Html.RadioButton("ChoiceList", item.score) @item.AnswerDesc</li>

                    }
                </ul>

                <input type="submit" value="Next" id="submitButton" />
            </fieldset>

        </div>
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to implement an AJAX POST using jQuery and return a JSON object that contains all the next Q&A info.   Use js/jQuery to set `<div>`'s or any other html element.  Posting back and reloading is such a pain and becoming an outdated approach.

For example you could have this ViewModel class:

```
public class Answer
{
    public int QuestionId {get; set;}
    public string Answer {get; set;}
}
```

Build a view that has a div & input control for the Q & A.

Implement the Answer Button to POST via AJAX:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Exam/HandleAnswer" ,
   data: { QuestionId:  _questionId, Answer: $("#txt_answer").val() },
  success: function (resp) {
    if (resp.Success) {
       $("#div_Question").text( resp.NextQuestionMessage);
       _questionId = resp.NextQuestionId,
       $("#txt_answer").val(''");  //clear
    }
    else {
      alert(resp.Message);
    }
   }
 });
```

In your ExamController:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult HandleAnswer(Answer qa)
{
     //use qa.QuestionId to load the question from DB...

     //compare the qa.Answer to what the DB says...

    //if good answer get next Question and send as JSON or send failure message..

   if (goodAnswer)
   {
      return Json(new { Success = true, NextQuestionMessage = "What is the capital of of Texas", NextQuestionId = 123});
   }
   else{
      return Json(new { Success = false, Message = "Invalid response.."});
   }

}
```